# Formula to calculate the max data capacity for QR codes?

Tags: qr-code

I've seen in several places on the web (e.g. [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes) and [here](http://blog.qr4.nl/page/QR-Code-Data-Capacity.aspx) and [here](http://www.qrcode.com/en/vertable1.html)) a table showing the number of characters each type of QR Code (1 to 40) can display depending on character type and EC level.

What I haven't been able to find or work out is the formula used to generate this table?

i.e. QR_Type & EC_Level & Character_Type => Max character length

I want to use this formula to work out the lowest QR type that can be used to display an input string, given a chosen EC level and by detecting the character set and string length.

Comment: You can calculate it with a table a and a formula. See my documented code of luaqrcode here: http://speedata.github.com/luaqrcode/docs/qrencode.html#section-5 (section "Capacity of QR codes").

Comment: Per one of the answerers, you can figure that out using this resource. http://www.qrcode.com/en/about/version.html Apparently QR data capacity calculation is a dumpster fire.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Thanks George, apparently so is my answer. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no formula for it. While it follows a general trend of course which you could approximate with a simple linear function, the exact cutoffs vary a bit due to roundings in several aspects -- number of codewords in a version, number of interleaves blocks, number of EC/data blocks. If you need an exact answer you need a table.

Comment: OK, thanks, that's good to know. Don't suppose you know of anywhere this table is already represented in code, or have I got a lot of typing ahead of me?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/core/src/com/google/zxing/qrcode/decoder/Version.java

Comment: Actually to be more correct, there is not *one* formula but rather there is an extensive *set* of multiple formulas based on the various tables of data, which in turn are based on the exact size and type of QR Code being calculated for.

Comment: There are 6 major formats of QR code:
Model 1, Model 2, Micro, iQR, SQRC, and Frame QR
incorporating up to 61 density levels (called "versions"),
4 encoding formats (number, alphanumeric, binary, and kanji),
5 error-correction protocols (L, M, Q, H, and S), and
2 different matrix layout formats (square and rectangular)
Plus the option of multiple concatenated matrices, each of which affects information capacity.